# AABB outline to AABB outline intersection points algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, collision-detection, aabb

I've looked around but haven't exactly found what I'm looking for. At first, I thought this would be a simple problem.. Until I tried to implement it and realized there were many cases and I could not find a generic solution.

Say, I have two AABBs. If their outlines intersect, I want to get all their points of intersection. The **maximum** amount of points is **4**, the **minimum non-zero** amount of points is **1**.

My AABBs are composed of a `min` and `max` point that are always automatically sorted so that `min` always has the **lowest** x-y values and `max` always has the **highest** x-y values.

The image below shows a few AABBs. The blue lines indicate their points of intersection. Note that if a side of an AABB overlaps another side, it's kind of like having an infinite amount of intersection points along the line-segments that overlap; in those cases, I want to ignore them and say, "There are no intersection points there".

Anyone got an idea for an algorithm?
I realize I haven't posted any code and I'm pretty sure that's frowned upon but I have thought about this problem quite a bit. As for **why** I want to do this.. I duno', I'm just curious as to whether it's possible to do this cleanly.

Oh, yeah, my AABBs have methods like these that should be useful:

```
Vector<2> getSize   () const;
Point<2>  getCenter () const;
//0=Quadrant-1, 1=Quadrant-2, 2=Quadrant-3, 3=Quadrant-4, else, error
Point<2> getCorner (int index) const;
//0=right, 1=up, 2=left, 3=down, else, error
LineSegment2D getSide (int index) const;
```

I could do an ugly hack and just do line-segment <-> line-segment checks but, I duno'.. It feels kinda', well, ugly and inelegant. I'm pretty sure there must be some trickery I could do with the `min` and `max` points to do this quickly.

[image: Example]

Comment: type this into a search engine : "check if squares intersect"

Comment: I do know how to check for AABB <-> AABB area intersection, containment and outline intersection. I just have trouble getting the exact points of outline intersection where they are, uhh, "well-defined".